# What kinds of error handling methods to consider for streaming ingestion into Snowflake?

Tags: error-handling, message-queue, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a streaming data via Message Queue that is coming in at 5 min to 15 min intervals. I am going to be ingesting this into Snowflake and I wanted to know what all error conditions I should code for while dealing with this kind of data. I am going to be first landing this in a table Stg A in snowflake with variant data type which I envision to be lean to hold the data during each iterative intervals. I intent to delete this table during each intervals of source ingestion depending on whether the data from the previous interval has been read by the next job. In the next stage table Stg B I would flatten out the json data into columns. Then I would load this into the third table Stg C combining this with other reference data. This will be exposed for real time dashboards.

Please advise what all error handling methods (native to Snowflake or user defined) can be incorporated for this use case.

Comment: If the data is structured the same, could you combine Stg B and C? For error handling, what are you using to ingest into Snowflake?

Comment: I am using a snow stage to pull the data from S3.